# In terraform, how should I create a secret manager instance and then create another one without destroying first one

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-ibm

I am creating secret manager instance using terraform called through jenkins.
I am providing an option to give the name.
`eg. options - ["abc", "xyz"]`

What I want is, if user selects "abc", an instance with name "abc" should be created. If second time, user selects "xyz", an instance should be create with name "xyz" but don't delete "abc" if its exists.

```
code - 
resource "ibm_resource_instance" "secret_manager_instance" {
   name = var.name
   service = "secrets-manager"
   ...
}
```

Here name is changing. Problem is, when second time the script executes, its sees change in name and tries recreating it with new name.
I want "abc" should exists and "xyz" should be created. Is there any way in terraform to perform this ?

Comment: should you update its version, more than its resource? ref: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/secretsmanager_secret_version

Comment: I think like that its not possible. You can at max use foreach, but then you need to track and manage your list of things outside terraform and pass it on create.

Comment: If you only want to create the instance and not manage it, then you need a new TF state for each JP execution, and each previous state can be discarded. Do you intend to also manage it?